# Error: write EPIPE at errnoException (net.js:770:11)

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have this system which attempts to send bulk emails written in NodeJS.

It uses 2 modules: fs (build into node v0.8.18) and nodemailer (from NPM, v0.3.42).

Now upon execution with `node newsletter.js` sometimes it will finish and complete, but sometimes it will randomly fail at a random point with the following error:

```
stream.js:81
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:594:19)
```

As far as i understand the EPIPE error occurs because the other end of a connection dropped and then we tried to write to that connection. All existing reports of this EPIPE error bug are in the context of opening a http connection or similar.

In what I have below the two things that could be causing the error is the `fs.readFileSync` in NewsletterEmail or the `mailer.send` in NewsleterMailer. Its more likely that the error would be in the mailer.send and nodemailer is opening a connection somewhere. However no error is being passed back up via a throw or callback error argument so there seems to be no way to see what is causing the error.

Most people suggest defining a error handler. However there is nothing in nodemailer or the fs module which allows me to define a error handler. The callback in nodemailer from the `mailer.send` call does pass an error argument in its callback, however this particular error isn't coming through there.

I have tried the following things:

- adding try/catch around both `fs.readFileSync` and the nodemailer transport sendEmail calls.
- Removing the fs.readFileSync calls and inlining the html - when i do this the error doesnt seem to occur. But again, the node docs have no indication that EPIPE errors should occur on readFileSync and there is certainly no way to add a error handler.

The code which triggers this error is below:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Provides a way to build newsletters when given a folder containing
 * the relevant template and images in a standard format. This folder
 * must contain a newsletter.html file, a newsletter.txt file and a images
 * directory containing any images.
 * 
 * @param {Object} settings The full folder path to the
 */
function NewsletterEmail(newsletterGroup, newsletterName)
{
    var folder = '/var/newsletters/' + newsletterGroup + '/' + newsletterName;
    this._html = fs.readFileSync(folder + '/newsletter.html', 'utf-8');
    this._text = fs.readFileSync(folder + '/newsletter.txt', 'utf-8');
}

NewsletterEmail.prototype.getSubject = function()
{
    return 'Testing';
}

/**
 * Generates the HTML version of a newsletter.
 *
 * @return {String}
 */
NewsletterEmail.prototype.buildHTML = function(email)
{
    var htmlPart = this._html;

    return htmlPart;
}

/**
 * Generates the text counterpart of a newsletter.
 * 
 * @return {String}
 */
NewsletterEmail.prototype.buildText = function(email)
{
    var textPart = this._text;

    return textPart;
}

/**
 * Creates a NewsletterEmail from the given folder.
 * 
 * @param  {String} folder The folder containing the html template, text template and images for a newsletter.
 * @return {NewsletterEmail}
 */
NewsletterEmail.create = function(newsleterGroup, newsletterName) {
    return new NewsletterEmail(newsleterGroup, newsletterName);
}

function NewsletterMailer(fromEmail)
{
    this._from = fromEmail;
    this._transport = nodemailer.createTransport('sendmail');
}

NewsletterMailer.prototype = {
    send: function(email, newsletterEmail, callback) {
        var mailOptions = {
            to: email,
            from: this._from,
            subject: newsletterEmail.getSubject(),
            html: newsletterEmail.buildHTML(email),
            text: newsletterEmail.buildText(email)
        };

        this._transport.sendMail(mailOptions, callback);

    },

    close: function() {
        this._transport.close();
    }
}

function Newsletter()
{
    this._id = 1;
    this.countSent = 0;
    this.emailsToSend = ['email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com', 'email3@example.com', 'email4@example.com', 'email5@example.com', 'email6@example.com'];
}

Newsletter.prototype.send = function() {
    var newsletter = this;

    var newsletterEmail = NewsletterEmail.create('company1', '2013-01-24-mynewsleter');
    var mailer = new NewsletterMailer('company@example.com');

    function sendEmail() {
        var email = newsletter.emailsToSend.pop();

        mailer.send(email, newsletterEmail, function(mailerErr) {
            if (mailerErr) {
                console.log('Mailer error: ', mailerErr);
            }

            newsletter.countSent++;

            console.log('progress ' + newsletter.countSent);

            if (newsletter.emailsToSend.length > 0) {
                sendEmail();
            }
            else {
                mailer.close();
                console.log('complete');
            }
        });
    }

    sendEmail();
}

var nl = new Newsletter();
nl.send();
```

Has anyone else come across similar errors? Do you have any tips for debugging or possible solutions.

With the stack trace given im at a bit of a dead end with this now. Below is the output of strace. Seems to always die on that mail mimepart boundary first:

```
futex(0x7f039c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(8, "------Nodemailer-0.3.42-?=_1-136"..., 131) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=13813, si_uid=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=13818, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
rt_sigreturn()                          = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
futex(0x7f039c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(8, "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC =22-//W3C/"..., 18098) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=13813, si_uid=0} ---
futex(0x7f039c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
close(8)                                = 0
epoll_wait(3, {{EPOLLIN|EPOLLHUP, {u32=9, u64=4294967305}}, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLHUP, {u32=11, u64=4294967307}}, {EPOLLIN, {u32=4, u64=4294967300}}}, 64, 0) = 3
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 9, {EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=4294967305}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 11, {EPOLLIN, {u32=11, u64=4294967307}}) = 0
read(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)          = 8
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 13818
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0x7fff2d6f4340) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(1, "progress 1\n", 11progress 1
)            = 11
socketpair(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0, [7, 8]) = 0
socketpair(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0, [10, 12]) = 0
socketpair(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0, [13, 14]) = 0
pipe2([15, 16], O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC)   = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f03a4b35a10) = 13820
close(16)                               = 0
poll([{fd=15, events=POLLIN|POLLHUP}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=15, revents=POLLHUP}])
close(15)                               = 0
close(7)                                = 0
ioctl(8, FIONBIO, [1])                  = 0
close(12)                               = 0
ioctl(10, FIONBIO, [1])                 = 0
close(14)                               = 0
ioctl(13, FIONBIO, [1])                 = 0
wait4(-1, 0x7fff2d6f529c, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f039c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
brk(0x932000)                           = 0x932000
read(11, "", 65536)                     = 0
close(11)                               = 0
read(9, "", 65536)                      = 0
futex(0x7f039c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
close(9)                                = 0
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(2, "events.js:71\n", 13events.js:71
```

Comment: The error occurs in `Socket.write` (net.js) so I would assume it's an issue with nodemailer. If you're running Linux, try running Node with strace, it might be that the MTA is just hanging up the connection for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the strace tip. Allows me to see what its actually doing. Have updated the post with the output of strace. Not sure how much it really tells me to be honnest. I really would have thought the nodemailer would handle things like the MTA hanging up and report it back via the error argument in the callback so you can deal with it.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/12267735/893780 (esp the comment on sendmail being installed)

Comment: Sendmail is definitely installed. If it wasnt i wouldnt expect it to work at all. This fails around 35% of the time, but succeeds the rest. More specifically its not sendmail installed its postfix with the sendmail compatibility interface (just a sendmail command it injects so its compatible with any software using regular sendmail).

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem then, although the strace does seem to suggest that delivering the message to the MTA is what's failing. No log messages in postfix-logs?

Comment: Postfix logs show nothing obvious. All looks like normal operation. 

Have tracked down the issue, Nodemailer is wrapping the contents of my mail at 75 characters. One of the lines in the text counterpart was exactly 76 characters long with a dot on the end. This meant the dot character was being wrapped to a line by itself. 

My understanding is that a dot on a line by itself indicates you are done writing to the connection. The connection is being closed prematurely. On the next write in the strace output the EPIPE error gets raised. So the solution is going to be somehow escaping that dot.

Comment: Good catch! Although it kinda sucks, nodemailer should take care of all that IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

This was caused by the nodemailer module wrapping lines at 75 characters. One line was exactly 76 characters long with a dot on the end. This dot was being wrapped onto its own line.

For SMTP servers a dot on a line by itself signifies the end of the message and the connection is closed. This was causing premature closure of the connection and subsequent writes were failing with the EPIPE error.

With the help of the nodemailer maintainer this has now been fixed in issue 0.3.43 by adding hte -i flag to the sendmail call which tells sendmail to allow lines with a single dot.

Further details available here: https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/issues/141.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it was bugging me for some time